# cabal benchmark bytestring: package has no benchmark

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I tried to run `cabal benchmark` on [bytestring](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring) I got `package has no benchmark`. Indeed, the `.cabal` file does not have benchmark configs. But the repo does have a bench directory. How does this work? Should I not try to benchmark it?

edit:

When running `cabal build` in the `bench` directory I got the following error:

```
Building bench-bytestring-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'bench-bytestring-builder' for
bench-bytestring-0.1.0.0...
[18 of 18] Compiling Main ( BenchAll.hs, dist/build/bench-bytestring-builder/bench-bytestring-builder-tmp/Main.o )

BenchAll.hs:133:46:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Benchmarkable’
            with actual type ‘IO ()’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘benchIntEncodingB nRepl e’
In the expression:
  bench (name ++ " (" ++ show nRepl ++ ")")
  $ benchIntEncodingB nRepl e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bench` directory has a separate Cabal file, [`bench-bytestring.cabal`](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/blob/0.10.6.0/bench/bench-bytestring.cabal). You should be able to `cd` into that directory and do `cabal run` to run the benchmarks.

That package's description explains why it works this way:

> This package is not meant for public release. It fixes a problem with the current benchmarking support in cabal, which has trouble compiling because criterion depends on bytestring. Here, we just include the whole source of the bytestring library directly.

Comment: I did see that and have tried building the `bench` directory both from itself and from its parent. Error is shown in update

Comment: It's likely that the benchmarks won't run. The `bench` directory has not been updated for two years. It looks like it was tested with GHC 7.0.3 and Criterion 0.5. Current versions are GHC 7.10.1 and Criterion 1.1.0.0. I would [open an issue against ByteString](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/new) if you want to run the benchmarks.